# Cannot dismiss "Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root"" notifcation

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage, notification

I received the notification
*Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root"*

[image]

at the top center of my screen.
None of the three options to press performs any action, and I cannot dismiss the notification.
So it obstructs my work.

**How can I get rid of it? (other that logging out/rebooting)**

Note that I do not want to stop receiving the notifications, but just dismiss this one.

**EDIT**:
I have freed some space and rebooted. Now I have ca. 3Gb free, and I will make some more space.
I am including the relevant info from `df` and Disk Usage Analyzer.
Note that I have my `/home` in the same partition as `/` (yikes...)

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       275G  257G  3,1G  99% /
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `df`, and a screenshot of the `Disk Usage Analyzer`.

Comment: @heynnema - I couldn't really work, so I rebooted... cannot reproduce anymore.
I am not sure if it is worth leaving the question...

Comment: You still have the problem of a full disk. Go ahead and give me the info requested. Have you emptied the trash?

Comment: @heynnema - Added requested info. Yes, I emptied the trash.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your hard disk is still very full. In the `Disk Usage Analyzer`, click on the triangle next to /home to determine what's using all the space.

Comment: @heynnema - Will do. I often check what can I do with `du --max-depth...`

Comment: `DUA` is much faster.